# How to delete data from StreamController in Flutter Provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am using provider to build my application, so the data is added to StreamController, and each time i refresh my app, it will call an API, and then push data to StreamController, and the question is how to remove the data before replacing with the new one?

```
   controller.add(user);
```

Comment: You don't. You just replace it by adding again, there's no need to remove it.

Comment: so, by adding the new one, it also remove the old one?

Comment: Yes. Just do `controller.add(newOne);`

Answer (score 1):

To iterate the answer from the comment. There is no need to remove any data added to the StreamController instead, just adding a new data again will remove the old data from there. You can do something like this:

```
controller.add(newOne);
```

You can also check [this reference](https://protocoderspoint.com/flutter-dart-stream-basic-example-fetch-crypto-currency-api-data/#Flutter_Streams_Basic_-_Count_Down_using_StreamController_StreamBuilder) to understand the concept of Stream with examples.